# let $a\sim b$ iff for some integer $k$, $a^k = b^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a group, 
 Let $a\sim b$ iff  for some integer $m$, $a^m = b^m$.

I am having a problem trying to figure out how to prove that the transitive property. I know that you start off by Assuming $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, such that $a^m = b^m$ and $b^n = c^n$ for some $m$, $n$ that exist in the integers. I am stuck and not sure where to go from here. I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The question isn't complete. You've merely defined a relationship. Presumably, you want to show something about this relationship?

Comment: @Thomas: He wants to prove that it’s transitive – probably as part of proving that it’s an equivalence relation, though that isn’t part of the question.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, but the question should really include, you know, the question @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Thomas: As far as I’m concerned, the first sentence of the second paragraph is quite sufficient to do that.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I am trying to prove that is an equivalence relation,sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $a^{mn}=b^{mn}$ and $b^{nm}=c^{nm}$.

**Remark:** The relation is uninteresting if we allow exponents to be $0$.

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question, but why does a^{mn} = b^{mn}?

Comment: We have $a^m=b^m$. It follows that $(a^m)^n=(b^m)^n$, or equivalently $a^{mn}=b^{mn}$.

Comment: Oh right, duh. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another approach. If $a^k = b^k$, then $a^k/b^k = (a/b)^k = 1$. Thus, $a\sim b$ iff $(a/b)^k$. Of course if an element has order dividing $k$, then so does its inverse, so $(b/a)^k = ((a/b)^{-1})^k = ((a/b)^k)^{-1} = 1^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: The question appears to regard more general group theory where manipulations like $a^k/b^k=(a/b)^k$ are problematic do to possible lack of commutativity.